# unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference for background colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I'm getting script error for below code. as I tried all the ways but no luck .
kindly help me as I'm very new to this field. atleast tell me where am I going wrong

```html
<body onload="hightlightMoreLink(2210);hightlightMoreLink(2211);">
```

```
function hightlightMoreLink(groupID) {
  var isHightlightRequired = top.document.Main.isOtherLabelingCountriesPresent(groupID)       var moreLinkColumnElement = "";
  var moreLinkElement = "";
  if (groupID == 2210) {
    moreLinkColumnElement = document.getElementById("MoreLinkTH");        
    moreLinkElement = document.getElementById("labelingMoreLink");
  } else { 
    moreLinkColumnElement = document.getElementById("MoreLinkTHUnblind");
    moreLinkElement = document.getElementById("labelingMoreLinkUnblind");
  }
  if (isHightlightRequired) {
    moreLinkColumnElement.style.backgroundColor = "#26339f";
    moreLinkElement.style.color = "#fff";
  } else {
    moreLinkColumnElement.style.backgroundColor = "#f5f5f5";
    (getting error on this line)
    moreLinkElement.style.color = "#26339f";
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the part of your HTML which contains the elements

Comment: What is your error?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is working...

```
function hightlightMoreLink(groupID) {
  var isHightlightRequired = 1           
  var moreLinkColumnElement="";
  var moreLinkElement="";

  if (groupID==2210) {
    moreLinkColumnElement = document.getElementById("MoreLinkTH");                
    moreLinkElement = document.getElementById("labelingMoreLink");
  } else {
    moreLinkColumnElement = document.getElementById("MoreLinkTHUnblind");
    moreLinkElement = document.getElementById("labelingMoreLinkUnblind");
  }
  if (isHightlightRequired) {
    moreLinkColumnElement.style.backgroundColor = "#26339f";
    moreLinkElement.style.color="#fff";
  } else {
    moreLinkColumnElement.style.backgroundColor = "#f5f5f5";
    moreLinkElement.style.color="#26339f";
  }
}

hightlightMoreLink(2210)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create a fiddle so people can better understand the problem.

Checking your code though, I think the problem is in this line:

```
var isHightlightRequired = top.document.Main.isOtherLabelingCountriesPresent(groupID)
```

Check if it is return a boolean.

Aside from that, I think you should work with classes to manipulate the elements' styles. The onload you're putting on the body is not a good practice either. Jquery has a function for that purpose.

```
$( document ).ready(){
    hightlightMoreLink(2210);
}
```

Another thing I would point out is the fact that you could use jquery to manipulate the elements. As is:

```
$("#MoreLinkTH").css("background-color", "#26339f");
$("#labelingMoreLink").css("color", "#fff");
```